# fetch data from Mysql to Angular-Calendar without using CalendarEvent

Tags: angular-calendar

I implemented the calendar using [that thread](https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink).

I'd like to consult data from **MySql** to **Calendar**.

I saved on **MySql** the data of an entity called **shedule**:

```
export class Schedule
{
    code: number;
    clas: string;
    room: string;
    teacher: string;
    module: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}
```

I'm asking if I can show the details of that entity (schedule) on calendar ?.

It's possible to do that without using `CalendarEvent` ?.

Big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show events on `Angular-Calendar`, I have to use `CalendarEvent`.
There's no documentation that allows to fetch data directly from an entity like `schedule`.
To resolve my problem, I have to use `CalendarEvent` like a bridge in that case.